# Is this a lost cause?

Tags: performance-reviews, teamleader

I'm a senior level developer with 10 years of experience. A year ago I started working for a major tech company at a smaller company they acquired 3-4 years ago and have been in the process of making more like the bigger company (procedures, tools, and so on). I was hired into a team that was understaffed. There was only 1 full timer, myself and a contractor. The team should've had at least 5-7 members. Management and team members all agreed this was the case. The team had also been understaffed for years. I did not know it at the time but on my 1st day there were enterprise customers on contracts worth well into six figures who had been waiting for 6-8 months for solutions & just getting smoke blown like "we're working on it".

Everyone else on the team and my immediate manager left when I had only been on the job for 6 months or so. I was not fully onboarded. Fast forward to now, and the new manager is giving me a bad review (not in writing but verbally). Basically blaming me for issues out of my control and for things I was ordered NOT to do anything about by management. He also claims that he has a hard time understanding me, when everybody else I have worked with at this company (and elsewhere) says the opposite. And he made it clear that I'm not his first choice to lead the team.

The "team" was just me for most of the last year but now I am training some people fresh out of school.

Is there any possible way to salvage this situation?

Comment: That's a lot of background and information, and not really clear what you ask for but opinions... If I needed to clarify your actual situation, I'd say : don't you think you're actually scooping out water of a sinking ship with the crew chief yelling at you for being too slow and while the captain is busy elsewhere?

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace @Zan ... I'd like to ask you to do some edits to your post. Currently it is very very long, try to cut side comments and details, keep only the core aspects and the goal you want to achieve... long posts are hard to follow, usually contain tangential details, and in general are not well received by the community (as it makes it difficult for us to help you). Please, shorten your post

Comment: @OldPadawan Thanks for the response. I will chop some of the question out to simplify it. And yes, I think it's a sinking ship unless I can somehow deal with different management.

Comment: @Zan VERY much concise and readable, nice :)

Comment: @Zan just to clarify, your goal here is (1) how to make new manager aware of the situation and ammend the "bad" verbal review or (2) how to train and salvage the situation with the new members you are training?

Comment: @DarkCygnus I'm wondering if it's even worth staying. Feel like I am being setup as a fall guy even tho several layers of management created this situation. Manager IS aware. Just don't think they will improve anything anytime soon. I wondered if anybody had been in this situation at a big company and found a way out that didn't involve jumping ship.

Comment: Not your job to keep the company afloat. It feels bad professionally to end up being associated with failing projects, but this is how they get you. Do not let the responsibility extend beyond the power in your hands, or get burnt. I'm still recovering from a situation similar to yours, it's been almost an year and it's just not worth it. Life's short, there are better things to do than going on a sinking ship against the wind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends a lot on what you mean by `salvage`

The situation that you describe with your new manager certainly doesn't sound like it can be salvaged without some work. It may be worth sitting down and formally finding out what his expectations are. Most managers would welcome any employee asking for that kind of feedback.

If the conversation goes really well, you could frankly and genuinely ask about your leadership opportunities. We don't know your manager's viewpoint, but from the amount of disfunction you describe in the post...he may be suffering a lot of your same pains just one level up the chain. True malice is rare....but miscommunication is rampant. Make sure you understand his point of view as best you can.

Training new talent fresh out of school is an excellent opportunity in most cases and can be one of the most fulfilling parts of being a senior engineer. BUT if you feel like you are digging your own grave, I understand your concern. Regardless, training them seems to be part of your current duties and must be carried out. Try to enjoy it and prepare them for their future.

Honestly, it just sounds like you are feeling under-appreciated in a  dysfunctional setting. Unless you care deeply about the company or its mission, I'd start refreshing my resume. There is a good deal of frustration in your post...I think that half of the question is whether or not you want to salvage the situation. If not, that's completely alright. And if you still don't feel like it's possible, that's also okay.

Best of luck!